# I am trying to create a slider for each product, with shareable state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, slider, state

I am creating a slider for each product item, and then clicking on right or left button changes the image based on its index that is linked with a shareable state.

```
<div className="CartItemImage" style={{position:'relative'}}>
                        {
                            item.gallery.length <= 1 ?
                            <img src={item.gallery[0]} alt={item.brand} style={{width:200}}/>:
                            <div>
                                <img src={item.gallery[this.state.imageSlide]} alt={item.btand} style={{width:200}} />
                                <div style={{position:'absolute' , display:'flex' ,right:"1rem" , bottom:"1rem"}}>
                                    <div onClick={()=> this.setState({imageSlide : this.state.imageSlide - 1})} style={this.state.imageSlide > 0 ? {width:24 , height:24 , backgroundColor:"#000" , marginRight:8 ,display:'flex',justifyContent:'center' , alignItems:'center'} : {pointerEvents:'none' , backgroundColor:"#000" , marginRight:8 ,display:'flex',justifyContent:'center' , alignItems:'center' , width:24}}><IoIosArrowBack color={COLORS.WhiteColor} size={18}/></div>
                                    <div onClick={()=> this.setState({imageSlide : this.state.imageSlide + 1})} style={item.gallery.length-1 > this.state.imageSlide ? {width:24 , height:24 , backgroundColor:"#000" ,display:'flex',justifyContent:'center' , alignItems:'center'} : {pointerEvents:"none" , backgroundColor:"#000" , display:'flex',justifyContent:'center' , alignItems:'center' , width:24}}><IoIosArrowForward color={COLORS.WhiteColor} size={18}/></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                        </div>
```

The problem: if there are many products the product's image changes with each other, even if I pointed to only one to change.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was is to make a separate component rendering inside the main component, that helps each slider works independency.